# Make files read-only when not checked out for editing with Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to make Mercurial have the working copy of a repository read-only, and require me to explicitly tell Mercurial that I want to edit a file before I am able to start editing it?

I'm *not* asking about locking to prevent concurrent editing, nor about preventing unintended changes finding their way into the repository. *This is about preventing unintended uncommitted changes in the working copy itself.*

I've tried creating a batch file checkout.bat that removes the read-only file attribute(s) and another checkin.bat that commits changes and makes the files read-only once more, but Hg expects files to be writeable when you do hg update.

I know that this is not the normal way to use Mercurial (and let's avoid arguments about whether the checkout-edit-checkin model is best avoided anyway). But switching to another version control system is not an option. (I use TFS for most projects, but this one requires Mercurial.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably be best served with a pair of `preupdate` and `update` hooks where the first makes all files in the repository writable and the second makes them readonly.

For example:

```
[hooks]
preupdate = hg files -0 | xargs -0 chmod u+w 2>/dev/null || true
update = hg files -0 | xargs -0 chmod u-w 2>/dev/null || true
```

Because you seem to be using Windows, a Unix shell script may not be the best solution and you may have to revert to Python (using Python would also eliminate the overhead of calling `hg` twice). This would be something along the following lines:

```
[hooks]
preupdate = python:.hg/pyhooks.py:make_writable
update = python:.hg/pyhooks.py:make_readonly
```

This requires a `pyhooks.py` file in `.hg` with something along the following lines:

```
import os, stat
from mercurial import scmutil

def make_writable(ui, repo, hooktype, node=None, source=None, **kwargs):
  ctx = scmutil.revsingle(repo, ".")
  for f in ctx:
    try:
      perm = os.stat(f)[0]
      os.chmod(f, perm | stat.S_IWUSR)
    except:
      pass

def make_readonly(ui, repo, hooktype, node=None, source=None, **kwargs):
  ctx = scmutil.revsingle(repo, ".")
  wflags = stat.S_IWUSR or stat.S_IWGRP or stat.S_IWOTH
  for f in ctx:
    try:
      perm = os.stat(f)[0]
      os.chmod(f, perm & ~wflags)
    except:
      pass
```

The above code is still written for Unix, but should also work for Windows (at least according to the documentation, `S_IWRITE == S_IWUSR` is the only flag that's looked at for `os.stat()` and `os.chmod()` on Windows).

You can obviously also put the file in a different place by adjusting the path in the hooks. Hooks are also not part of the repository proper and if you clone the repository elsewhere, you will have to add them to your `.hg/hgrc` file again.

Finally, note that there is a potential performance impact here: These hooks change permissions on *all* files in the repository twice for each update, which can be expensive in large repositories.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of [hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) that get called whenever certain operations are performed on a Mercurial repository or a working copy. What you need is an `update` hook, where you could theoretically change attributes.

Note that by default hooks are "local", meaning that they do not propagate to clones of repositories. To fix this, there's a [ProjRc](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ProjrcExtension) extension, which you can use to "distribute" hook settings.